# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined highcharts highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have four highstock charts "Compare multiple series" in one view 
Sometimes they load all well, but sometimes random does not load and give error: "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined".

There is my code: http://pastebin.com/3He5ahzd

I dont have any idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are you the loading the js file into your html document?  Usually these types of error occur because things are loaded out of order. For example, you are trying to add a chart to a div that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Hi, 
script is at the end of body section
before function is:   
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you load series for a chart incorrectly.

The code for reproducing the error. [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwwsz2kz/)

```
var series = [];
series[1] = {
  data: [1,2,3]
};
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: series
});
```

The error is caused by the series array which is `length = 2` but the first element is undefined. In your code it is caused by incorrect usage of ajax requests. The chart can be created before the first ajax request fill the series variable. You should nest the callbacks or use other methods for preventing the race of ajax requests.

```
        var seriesOptionsmaxload = [];
        $.getJSON('/test/statistics/5/list?parameter=maxLoad&type=wats', function (max) {
            seriesOptionsmaxload[0] = {
                name: 'Maksymalne obciążenie',
                color: '#ff0000',
                data: max
            };

          $.getJSON('/test/statistics/5/list?parameter=maxLoad&type=perKg', function (max) {
            seriesOptionsmaxload[1] = {
                name: 'W/kg',
                color: '#085fbc',
                data: max
            };
            Highcharts.stockChart('maxLoad', {
            ...
            });

          });
```

Comment: Ok i make that

i use block when and then, 
When 
    get firstJson,
    get secondJson
Then
    generate chart 

That works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this a 2nd time and now I know what causes it.

When your graph data has series data like this:

```
series: [1, 2, null, 3, 4]
```

OR

```
series: [1, 2, undefined, 3, 4]
```

It will throw this error because `highstock.src.js` reveals that highstock iterates through each item in the array and checks the type property like so:

```
i = seriesOptions && seriesOptions.length;
while (!value && i--) {
  klass = seriesTypes[seriesOptions[i].type]; // ERROR THROWN HERE
  if (klass && klass.prototype[key]) {
    value = true;
  }
}
```

To prevent this error you can:

(1) remove all non objects from your array

OR

(2) use the alternative series format as follows:

```
series: [{
  data: [1, 2, undefined, 3, 4]
}]
```

which will avoid this error.